# How to add 4 hours to a formated date/time

Tags: javascript, date

I've used Date Format 1.2.3 to format my time into yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss and used it for a startTime variable. How can add 4 hours to the startTime string and use it for a new variable (endTime)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to parse it as `Date`, add 4 hours and then format it into text again.

```
var d = new Date(startTime);
d.setHours(d.getHours() + 4);
var endTime = // Format d variable as you like
```

Comment: I get bit confused though because I've already parsed the startTime:

    `var date = Date.parse(startTime);`
    `var startTime = dateFormat(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss');`

Do i need to parse it again? Or am i missing something really obvious?

Comment: I think I have it - check it tomorrow for sure - thanks!
  `date.setHours(date.getHours() + 4);
var endTime = dateFormat(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss');`

Comment: I still can't get this to work. I can get the initial startDate fine but the endTime doesnt come out at all:
 `var input = document.getElementById("descsEd").innerHTML; 
 var date = Date.parse(input);
  var startDate = dateFormat(date, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss');
  alert(startDate);
                     var d = Date.parse(startDate);
                                  d.setHours(d.getHours() + 4);
                                  var endDate = dateFormat(d, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:MM:ss');
                                  alert(endDate);`

Comment: There was a small issue with my sample code (instead of Date.parse() call, new Date() had to be called).  Now it should work (I tested it and it's working on http://jsfiddle.net/TeeJ5/1/)

Comment: Thank you - but not sure if that worked? I don't get the endTime variable, it doesnf't fire the alert for it?

Comment: Correct, parsing such a date format seems to fail in Internet Explorer, for instance (I tested it on IE8 and it throws an error).  If you don't need parsing, you can use the initial "date" variable to add 4 hours to it.  If you need parsing, try using a more powerful JS library such as datejs (http://www.datejs.com/).

Comment: Its for an app so not fussed about IE. Got it working with a variation on your code and the original dateformat.js so very happy now:
http://jsfiddle.net/vkgmw/5/

Comment: Great! Happy to be helpful. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Parse it as a date then add 4 to the hours

Here's an example with the date object

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(today.getHours() + 4);
```

Javascript will automatically update the day/month/year if required